# How I can I implement both JWT Authentication and Identity Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

I want to create an app that can provide an environment for the web and API for mobile apps. Authentication and Authorization, of course, is needed and I think Identity is good for the web while JWT is good for the Mobile so I decide to use them both. What I think of my project is that authorization api can be used whether by an Identified User or a generate token. The problem is when I implement them both, the Identity method is the only one that I can use. How can I fix this?

My startup.cs implement for both:

```
services.AddAuthentication("DemoAuth").AddJwtBearer("DemoAuth", config =>
            {
                var secretByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Constants.SECRET);
                var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretByte);
                config.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("access_token"))
                        {
                            context.Token = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    assembly => assembly.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName))
                    .UseLazyLoadingProxies())
                .AddIdentity<User, Role>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultUI().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Edit - I have found a solution to enable both of them to exist in my project. But I have a new problem. Whichever authentication method declares first is the default one and it still refuses to share the right to authenticate the same api. If I want to apply the second one, I have to specifically declare it to use that thus it also becomes unavailable for the first one.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCookie(config => config.SlidingExpiration = true)
                .AddJwtBearer(config =>
            {
                config.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                config.SaveToken = true;

                config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Constants.PJ,
                    ValidAudience = Constants.PJ,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Constants.SECRET))
                    
                };
            });

        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public IActionResult Secret()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: your `AuthorizeAttribute` need to be specified with all schemes it supports, in your code, it's just `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, you need to provide a comma-separated list of schemes that can be used to authorize the resource access.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know how or there's a proper method to provide a schemes for Identity.

Comment: Identity is not a scheme, internally it uses Cookies Authentication, that's the scheme you need.

Comment: Note that when using Identity, you use its models and various patterns, finally it still uses one of the authentication schemes, by default it's the cookies authentication. The process of logging-in is done by Identity api but that's not authentication. The authentication process is done after the first time logging-in, usually performed by authentication middleware, the authentication cookies will be extracted/parsed for the original authentication ticket (that's built and set by the Identity api after logging-in successfully before).

Comment: actually there are different schemes that can be used by Identity, you can find the values in this `IdentityConstants`. There cookies authentication is classified as `ApplicationScheme` and `ExternalScheme`, you can use both of that, or all the others (for two-factor authentication) as well